# Turn off [turn-off] for good

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Looks like [turn-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turn-off) is a valueless muddle of ambiguity. The *highest-rated* questions have to do with [triggering events upon] "turning off" the monitor or computer or phone (?), *nix logging (??), an IDE preference (!), WiFi or microphone (!!), McAfee (?!), and so forth. In nearly all of these cases, the tag is redundant with a better tag (usually not one that's applied).

With only 24 questions to go through, seems like a single 2k+ can probably manage this fairly easily.

Comment: It looks like someone has taken care of your request: 0 questions remain.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just went through them all. It was a useless tag - people used it for everything. Removed all instances of the tag, and edited to fix grammar and formatting/voted on duplicates and off-topic where needed.

Comment: I agree (and I assume many others would as well), but typically it's proper to wait ~1 week for community consensus before taking burnination into your own hands (for future reference).

Comment: @AstroCB just 24 question trough, and no "top user" either. Nobody will miss it.

Comment: @Braiam True, which is why I agree in this case; I just thought I'd leave that for future cases.

Comment: @AstroCB thanks for the comments, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Hope you also did all the additional cleanup / voting which might have been indicated...

Comment: @Deduplicator edited all posts to fix grammar and formatting, voted duplicates/off-topic where needed :)